# In R shiny, how to embed an observeEvent function in the renderUI section?

Tags: r, shiny

I am having problems in working with renderUI in Shiny.

In the below MWE code, the user has the option to alter the inputs for the slider (`periods`) and the first matrix grid (`base_input`) from their default values (only the 1st row of this matrix1, row "A", is activated for this MWE).

The user also has the option to create a multi-variable vector for that "A" variable by clicking on the "Show" button, and inserting values into the 2nd matrix (`vector_input`) that pops up in that same sidebar panel. This works fine. As one changes inputs in the slider and first row/column of matrix1 (so long as matrix2 has appeared by having clicked on "Show"), the 1st row of matrix2 reflects those changes reactively which is how it is intended to work. (Note that for inputting into that 2nd matrix, you must 1st click and enter into the right column before inputting into the left column - this is due to a minor bug in shinyMatrix which I have the fix for but not yet implemented).

My question is: how can I adapt this so changes to slider and matrix1 are reflected in matrix2 BEFORE clicking on the SHOW button which triggers renderUI?

So if the user has made any changes to slider/matrix1 inputs before clicking on SHOW, and then SHOW is clicked, then those changes to slider/matrix1 are already reflected in matrix2.

It seems that the observeEvent below that links slider/matrix1 to matrix2 should be embedded in the renderUI section to make the above work, but when I try it it doesn't work. Any solutions?

Also, I don't want clicking on the "Hide" button to reset the values back to default in that matrix2.

I post some images below to make this clearer.

Below is the MWE code:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyMatrix)
library(shinyjs)

ui <- 
  pageWithSidebar(
    headerPanel("Model..."),
    sidebarPanel(
      conditionalPanel(condition="input.tabselected==2",
          sliderInput('periods','',min=1,max=120,value=60),
          matrixInput(
            "base_input",
            value = matrix(c(0.2), 4, 1, dimnames = list(c("A","B","C","D"),NULL)),
            rows = list(extend = FALSE,  names = TRUE),
            cols = list(extend = FALSE, names = FALSE, editableNames = FALSE),
            class = "numeric"),
                       
          h5(strong("Vectorize variables:")), # Adds a line of text
          # Action buttons to conditionally show/hide performance vectors:
          useShinyjs(),
          actionButton('showPerfVectorBtn','Show',style="width:9vw"), 
          actionButton('hidePerfVectorBtn','Hide',style="width:9vw"),
          uiOutput("Vectors")
      )), # close conditional and sidebar panels
    
  mainPanel(
    tabsetPanel(
      tabPanel("Dynamic", value=2,
               helpText("Dynamic B")),
        id = "tabselected"))
  ) # close page with sidebar

server <- function(input,output,session)({
  # --- Set reactive input variables
  periods       <- reactive(input$periods)
  base_input    <- reactive(input$base_input)
  vector_input  <- reactive(input$vector_input)
  
  # --- Link first row of vector input grids to base_input matrix
  observeEvent(input$periods|input$base_input,{
    updateMatrixInput(session,"vector_input", 
                      value=matrix(c(input$periods,input$base_input[1,1]),1,2, 
                                   dimnames=list(NULL, c("Y","Z")))
    ) # close update matrix
  }) # close observe event
  
  # --- Action buttons to conditionally show/hide performance vectors
  output$Vectors <- renderUI({
    req(input$showPerfVectorBtn)
    tagList(
        matrixInput(
          "vector_input",
          value = matrix(c(1,0.2),1,2,dimnames=list(NULL,c("Y","Z"))),
          rows = list(extend = TRUE,  names = FALSE),
          cols = list(extend = FALSE, names = TRUE, editableNames = FALSE),
          class = "numeric")
    ) # close tag list    
  }) # close render UI
  
  observeEvent(input$showPerfVectorBtn,{shinyjs::show("Vectors")})
  observeEvent(input$hidePerfVectorBtn,{shinyjs::hide("Vectors")})
  # --- Captures inputs as global variables
  observeEvent(periods(), {periods.R <<- periods()})
  observeEvent(base_input(), {base_input.R <<- base_input()})  
  observeEvent(vector_input(), {vector_input.R <<- vector_input()})
}) # close server section

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution is much simpler than I thought. I fiddled with it some more, looked at the code hard to make sure I understand.

In the `matrixInput` function, within the `renderUI` function of the `Server` section in the MWE code posted above, see the line that reads `value = matrix(c(1,0.2),1,2,dimnames=list(NULL,c("Y","Z")))`.

To make this work as described above, just change the matrix definition in that line **FROM** `c(1,0.2)` **TO** `c(input$periods,input$base_input[1,1])`. That was an oversight on my part. Now, with this change to matrix definition, the first row of the matrix2 values are completely reactive and linked to the slider (period) and matrix1 row A (base_input) values in all usage scenarios.